# How to build project in CLion for linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, clion

I'm new in CLion and CMake and try to build my project for Linux. In IDE it's work fine. But after building I try to run it with MakeFile and it do nothing. I think that problem with `CMakeList.txt`. Can someone check and explain how to correctly build project.
My `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(POng2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch- 
0/203.7717.62/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.17/Modules")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)


include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(POng2 main.cpp Game.h Game.cpp Paddle.h Paddle.cpp Entity.h Entity.cpp Ball.h
    Ball.cpp Board.h Board.cpp Score.h Score.cpp)

target_link_libraries(POng2 ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
    ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES})
```

Files after building:
[image]

Comment: "i try to run it with MakeFile and it do nothing" - Please, elaborate this. We don't know the code of your executable, so we don't know the reason of "do nothing". You may add "print"-like statements to your code, and find out which line is executed unexpectedly or give unexpected result. Alternatively, you may run your executable under debugger.

Answer (score 0):

CLion uses CMake for generation build files.

For default CMake uses `GodeBlock - Unix Makefile` generator to create Makefile which can be built with `make`.

So if you want to build your app outside CLion you just need to run `make` in your build directory or you can use CMake to call build tool by run `cmake --build . --target POng2`.